# HTML email select text in element

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I am trying to add to an **HTML email** an element in this case an anchor where the content of this element "Hello" can be selected on click/on touch by the recipient.

```
<div>
  <a>Hello</a>
<div>
```

I have tried adding this style inlined:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: default;
  -webkit-user-select: all;
   -khtml-user-select: all;
     -moz-user-select: all;
      -ms-user-select: all;
          user-select: all;
```

but this inline style is ignored (stripped from the html when opening the email in gmail web app for example.

Comment: you mean like a pointer cursor ?

Comment: I just mean the user click (or tap on mobile) the word hello and the whole word hello is selected on first click/tap. I guess just "Hello" isn't a very good example actually as it's just one word so instead let's say: ```<div>
  <a>Hello world</a>
<div>```  user click (or tap on mobile) the word "Hello world" and the whole sentence is selected on first click/tap, exactly like what user-select: all; does in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an advanced feature of CSS (CSS3) and as such most email clients do not support it. They barely support the basics!